# Elastic Beanstalk doesn't accept headers from Axios

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, react-native, axios, lumen

I am making a React Native App with a Lumen API as the backend. I want to protect all my routes with a simple middleware. I have modified the **AuthServiceProvider** to check whether the request has a header with the token, if it does check whether that token belongs to a user.

### AuthServiceProvider

```
$this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
        if($request->header('access_token')){
            return User::where('access_token', $request->header('access_token'))->first();
        }

        return null;
    });
```

A simple **Axios** request would look like this,

```
axios.get('url/to/site', {headers:{access_token: '12345667890ABC'}})
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => err.response);
```

The routes are placed inside the **auth** middleware in web.php file. I know that while working with mobile Apps we don't have to worry about CORS, so that isn't the problem.

Strangely enough the code seems to work on my localhost and authenticates the user, however when I deploy to AWS ElasticBeanstalk it returns **unauthorized**. I am using the free tier of AWS for now. My instance is running **Amazon Linux AMI**

I have also tried setting the **axios** headers as such;

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['access_token'] = '12345667890ABC';
```

And just for peace of mind I added some additional headers via another middleware in Lumen as well.

```
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'access_token')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

I have tested local and AWS routes from Postman as well, both with and without the access_token. The result is the same, it works for localhost but does not work for AWS, where the **header** access_token is just missing.

At first I thought the problem might be a config or permission issue on AWS but I have also tried the whole process on a simple shared hosting account and the middleware still does not authenticate the request via Postman.

Comment: are you serving with apache? is there a difference in that setup between your local host and the aws one?

Comment: Yes there is .. AWS instance has Apache on my localhost I use MAMP which uses nginx. I came across an amazon tutorial which said I had to use one of their services (I don't remember) to allow custom headers in my instances. I diverted to using Authorization Header. This solution works for me

Answer (score 6):

Remove underscores from the header variables, example:- header_var_val = "some value" **replace it with** --> headervarval = "some value"

Comment: It worked for me. Headers keys with an underscore in it do not work and even camelCase doesn't work, but headers with hyphen work.

Comment: It works for me too after removing the underscore (_)