# Laravel 8 Query Works locally but not on server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am debugging an API call on a Laravel 8 app, that uses a **_token** parameter in the header. The following query returns a result locally:

```
$user= User::where('_token',$token)->first();
```

But not on production. Both the local environment and production environment are connected to the same DB (AWS RDS Aurora MySQL).

I would like to know what causes this issue, or how to debug it. Thank you

**Local**
[image: Local Server]

**Production**
[image: Production Server]

**Code**

```
function getJson($fileName,Request $request){
        $user=$this->verifyToken($request->header('_token'));
        if(!isset($user->id)){  
            return response()->json(['error_code'=>'201', "error_message" => 'please enter valid user token']); 
        }
        try {
            $data=[];
            $files = File::allFiles(public_path('json-data/'.$fileName)); 

            foreach($files as $path){
                          // print_r($path);
                $file = pathinfo($path);
                $dirname= $file['dirname'] ;
                $basename= $file['basename'] ;
                $extension= $file['extension'] ;
                $filename= $file['filename'] ;

                if($fileName=='general'){
                    $data=  json_decode(strtolower(file_get_contents(public_path('json-data/'.$fileName.'/'.$basename))));
                }else{
                    $d=(array)json_decode(strtolower(file_get_contents(public_path('json-data/'.$fileName.'/'.$basename))));
                    $d=array_unique($d);
                    $data=  (array_merge($data,$d)); 
                }

            }                
                       // $data=(array)$data;
            return response()->json(['error_code'=>200, "error_message" => '','data'=>  ($data)]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error_code'=>'204', "error_message" => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }

      

public function verifyToken($token=''){
            try {
                if($token != ''){
                    $user= User::where('_token',$token)->first();
                    return $user;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return ['error_code'=>'204', "error_message" => $e->getMessage()];

            }
          }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('get-json/{fileName}','apiController@getJson');
```

Comment: check token value in production - I think, problem is not in query.

Comment: You'll have to debug the SQL being run. Turn on SQL logging via `DB::enableQueryLog()` before that query, then `DB::getQueryLog()` after it to see what's being run

Comment: please provide more information about two scenarios, ie: request details including headers

Comment: Are you able to get other data from aurora on prod? is this the only data you can't get?

Comment: Please can you show all the controller code (or at least the method(s) responsible for the route). A 201 HTTP response is to indicate that a resource has been created.

Comment: @apokryfos Other API calls I have tested locally and on production seem to work fine. I did not write the code. Just this API call causes issues.Thanks

Comment: I have added the relevant code @Rwd Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

In case it helps anyone. Checking the value in production helped debugging the issue. The header name had underscore. `_token`
Removing `_` or passing the `_token` via a parameter solves the issue. Apparently AWS Beanstalk does not accept underscore in headers.

**Related Issue**
[Elastic Beanstalk doesn't accept headers from Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917024/elastic-beanstalk-doesnt-accept-headers-from-axios)